# ошибка exec: "dir": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: golang

код d liteide :

```
// mycmd2 project main.go

package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("dir")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Waiting for command to finish...")
    err = cmd.Wait()
    log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
}
```

c:/go/bin/go.exe build [C:/Users/User/go/src/mycmd2]
Успех: процесс завершился с кодом 0.
C:/Users/User/go/src/mycmd2/mycmd2.exe  [C:/Users/User/go/src/mycmd2]
2020/01/29 14:27:49 exec: "dir": executable file not found in %PATH%

==================================================================
при установке go добавил переменную среды сам GOPATH %USERPROFILE%\go
и я после ошибки ставил c:\go\bin но при запуске та же ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по
[вот этому списку](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/Windows/System32/cmd_exe/commands/index),
`dir` является встроенной командой, а не бинарём.  Попробуйте
запустить что-то другое, например `notepad.exe`.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/438394)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  Я понимаю, что вы из очереди проверок, но в данном случае ссылка — всего лишь доказательство к ответу.  А сам ответ в том, что `dir`, скорее всего, не бинарь.